# How can I find the second value in a comma separated list (array) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ms-access

I am trying to get the second value in field to populate a column in a query.
Example:

[image: data.PNG]

I was able to accomplish this using MS Access and the SQL statement looks like this:

```
    SELECT stone_schedules.mach_equip_id,
    stone_schedules.timeline,
    IIf(InStr(1,Mid([timeline],InStr(1,[timeline],",")+1),",")=0,0,Mid(Mid([timeline],InStr(1,[timeline],",")+1),1,InStr(1,Mid([timeline],InStr(1,[timeline],",")+1),",")-1)) AS NextSchedEntry_id
    FROM stone_schedules
    WHERE (((stone_schedules.active)<>"0"));
```

The problem with running this in Access and not on the server is that it runs too slow and server side is able to run this a lot quicker. This is what I have so far server side in pgAdmin:

```
    SELECT 
      schedules.mach_equip_id, 
      schedules.timeline,
      --select function where I need help 
    FROM 
      stone.schedules
    WHERE
    schedules.active = true;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I was able to find an answer that is easier than the solution from ms access and my guess is probably less expensive. 
When values are separated like that and inside the curly braces, it is an array. 
I was able to select the 2nd value of the array by using the following sql statement.

```
    SELECT 
      schedules.mach_equip_id,
      schedules.timeline,
      schedules.timeline[2]  -- using brackets made it possible to select the 2nd value
    FROM 
      stone.schedules
    WHERE
      schedules.active = true;
```

That was easier than I thought it would be.